# Delayed job picking attributes from table differently in different environments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I am using delayed job to queue a `Model` method in another `Model` like this:

**article_loader.rb**

```
date_value_in_string =  "2017-06-21 07:17:00"
Article.delay(:queue => 'article_load').article_loading([date_value_in_string])
```

Even though I have passed a String as an argument to the method, inside the method it gets converted to Time object in the production environment.

**article.rb** in production environment

```
def self.article_loading(args)
  date_value = args[0]
  p date_value.class # Time
end
```

While in development environment it is a string.

**article.rb** in development environment

```
def self.article_loading(args)
  date_value = args[0]
  p date_value.class # String
end
```

I don't know why this happens. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have different default date formats set on the environments in config/locales/en.yml? That might account for it.

Comment: No, I haven't set a different default date format in config/locales/en.yml.